# How can I bypass this issue? SQL Error ORA-00904

Tags: sql, oracle, alias, calculated-columns

I'm into troubles with this code:

```
SELECT 
s.codcli,
s.consfin consistenza_iniziale, 
s.periodo,
ss.consfin consistenza_finale,
ss.periodo,
(SELECT sum(quanti) somma_bonifici_ingresso 
FROM mov WHERE tipope IN ('VE1', 'VE5', 'VE9') AND (datope BETWEEN to_date('01-01-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND to_date('30-07-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) AND mov.codcli = s.codcli 
GROUP BY codcli, tipope) as somma_bonifici_ingresso,
(SELECT sum(quanti) somma_bonifici_ingresso 
FROM mov WHERE tipope IN ('PR1', 'PR5', 'PR9') AND (datope BETWEEN to_date('01-01-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND to_date('30-07-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) AND mov.codcli = s.codcli 
GROUP BY codcli, tipope) as somma_bonifici_uscita,
(ss.consfin - (somma_bonifici_ingresso - somma_bonifici_uscita) - s.consfin)/s.consfin as variazione 
FROM  sre s
LEFT JOIN sre ss on s.codcli = ss.codcli
WHERE s.periodo=to_date('01-01-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
AND ss.periodo=to_date('30-06-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
AND s.consfin>0 
ORDER BY s.codcli
```

I'm getting an 00904 error not a valid identifier. I need to insert a new column arranging the columns somma_bonifici_ingresso and somma_bonifici_uscita. I have to do some calculations but it seems like it isn't able to find those columns I guess for the aliases...

Comment: Without a definition of the tables you are querying, it's also guessing for us.

Comment: You should also specify the exact error and the line/column numbers that it presumably gave you that it was referring to. I don't think there's enough info to work with here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-use a column alias in the same `select`, so use a subquery:

```
SELECT s.*,
       (consistenza_iniziale - (somma_bonifici_ingresso - somma_bonifici_uscita) - consistenza_iniziale) / consistenza_iniziale as variazione 
FROM (SELECT s.codcli, s.consfin as consistenza_iniziale, s.periodo,
             ss.consfin as consistenza_finale, ss.periodo,
             (SELECT sum(quanti) 
              FROM mov
              WHERE tipope IN ('VE1', 'VE5', 'VE9') AND
                    (datope BETWEEN DATE '2016-01-01' AND DATE '2017-07-30') AND
                    mov.codcli = s.codcli 
             ) as somma_bonifici_ingresso,
             (SELECT sum(quanti) 
              FROM mov
              WHERE tipope IN ('PR1', 'PR5', 'PR9') AND
                    (datope BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND DATE '2017-07-30') AND
                    mov.codcli = s.codcli 
             ) as somma_bonifici_uscita,
      FROM sre s LEFT JOIN
           sre ss 
           ON s.codcli = ss.codcli
      WHERE s.periodo = DATE '2016-01-01' AND
            ss.periodo = DATE '2017-07-30' AND
            s.consfin > 0
     ) s
ORDER BY codcli;
```

Other notes:

- Use date constants instead of literals.  `DATE` for dates and `TIMESTAMPS` if there is a time.
- Check your dates.  There are differences between the dates in the subqueries and outer `WHERE`.
- The `GROUP BY` is unnecessary -- and bad -- in the subqueries.  You could end up with a "too many rows returned" error.

Comment: In addition to Gordon's comments, I'm wondering if you really need to move the `ss.periodo = DATE '2017-07-30'` predicate from the where clause to the left join clause. Depends on what you want the output to be, I guess!

Comment: Hi, I'm getting this error code now: ORA-00936 missing expression